# Forcing your mac or pc to sleep

Tags: angularjs, electron

I am trying to find a way of make my computer (a Mac) sleep programmatically from an electron / angular application. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. First install shelljs with

```
npm install shelljs
```

In your app, you now need to import this module with

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
```

To make your mac go to sleep, simply use

```
shell.exec('pmset sleepnow');
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I needed just to add   shell.config.execPath = '/usr/local/bin/node';  Btw, do you know what changes are needed for the current versions of Linux & Windows?

Comment: For Linux there shouldn't be any big changes needed as ShellJS is supposed to work with all Unix based systems. You'd just need to find a shell command to make the Linux machine go to sloop. For Windows it's a lot more complicated as far as I can see. I'm not really an expert when it comes to Windows so I can't help you with that.